# Excel 2016 (Office 365) Series Data Display Order

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I have run into a seemingly simple problem that I can’t seem to figure out even though I have found countless topics about it on the internet. What I am trying to do is simply make one series of data in an Excel chart show as visible on top of any other series data that I have showing on the same chart.

Typically, I would just go to the “Source Data” option window from the right click menu and either move up or move down the data series to re-order them appropriately. However, no matter which order I have the series in some of the data points on my most prominent series are getting covered up by other data point markers from data points.

So my question is; are you aware of any other “features” that Excel may have that would counteract the standard series data order sequence of how the series look plotted on the screen?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few behaviors you need to understand.

Series on secondary axes appear in front of those on primary axes.

In a combination chart, series chart types have a hierarchy as well. Areas are always in back, then bars and columns, then lines, then XY Scatter. But within line series, and within scatter series, if one has markers and no line, it will appear in front of another with markers and lines or just with lines, despite the plot order of the series.

Confused yet?